# How to convert ScreenToViewportPoint vector back to world units in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to get an object to fallow the mouse position and I'm using `ScreenToViewportPoint` to get the mouse position, because I want to use this on a mobile device.

```
Vector3 position = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);

transform.position = position;
```

The problem is that the bottom-left of the camera is (0,0); the top-right is (1,1) when using `ScreenToViewportPoint`, so I need to convert the `position` to the World position

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

Then, you may need to change the z coordinate of the result to 0 or whatever you need to place the cube at the right height over the plane.